# Question about 'ensure' token in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a little question about how ruby interprets de ensure clause in the code.
As i know, ensure clause must always be enclosed by **begin** and **end** tokens.

For example, if i write this piece of code a kENSURE error will be raised (C:/Documents and Settings/jlomonaco/Desktop/borrar.rb:3: **syntax error, unexpecte
d kENSURE, expecting $end**)

```
x=5
raise "ERROR!!!" if x==5
ensure
puts "some code has been executed"
```

However if I wrap this code between **begin** and **end** clauses no error will be raised:

```
begin
x=5
raise "ERROR!!!" if x==5
ensure
puts "some code has been executed"
end
```

So here comes my question:

I have discovered that **inside a function** definition isn't obligatory to wrap the ensure token between begin and end; for example i could just write this code and no errors will be raised:

```
def stackoverflow
 x=5
 raise "ERROR!!!" if x==5
ensure
 puts "some code has been executed"
end

stackoverflow
```

And if i write the begin and end tokens the code works well too. ***So where is it obligatory to put the BEGIN and END clauses?***

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is documented in [The Ruby Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177):

> Throughout this discussion of
>   exception handling, we have described
>   the rescue, else, and ensure keywords
>   as clauses of a begin statement. In
>   fact, they can also be used as clauses
>   of the def statement (defines a
>   method), the class statement (defines
>   a class), and the module statement
>   (defines a module). Method definitions
>   are covered in Chapter 6; class and
>   module definitions are covered in
>   Chapter 7.

I've found this to be a great reference book.

Answer (score 3):

Based on a little experimentation, ensure seems to be valid in begin, def, class, and module blocks (i.e. definitions + begin), but not at the top level and not in loops, conditionals, or do blocks / { |args| ... }.

Comment: Yes i think my question is very subtle and the answer is on experimentation as u said! Thanks for that information!

Comment: Good answers need facts and not speculation.

Comment: The results of experiments are facts. But I see your point; it's usually better to reference documentation (like Mark Westling does) than poke around with the interpreter, so I'll vote up Mark's answer.

Comment: Of course, i prefer a book reference rather than an answer based on expermintation; but as this question was too specific i doubt that it has a 'book' answer. Anyway your expermientations and conclusions were correct wdebeam, thanks a lot again :)